# Is there such a thing as too many chromecast devices on one network?

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

I have an app that uses the CastCompanionLibrary and I'm having a weird issue. On a small network with one chromecast device my application is able to detect it and show the MediaRouterItem.

Although, I had a beta tester say that they were not able to get any of their devices detected, so the icon never shows up for them. Come to find out they are connected to a larger, shared network with multiple chromecast devices connected to it. They said that they are able to detect all of the chromecast devices with other apps such as YouTube and Localcast though. Which is weird because that leads me to believe that maybe I'm not doing something right with the discovery process.

Unfortunately, I am not in a position where I can have a network with multiple chromecast devices to debug this issue, so I was just wondering if anyone else had a similar issue? Or is there a certain method that you have to call with the CastCompanionLibrary that I'm missing?

**EDIT**

I am using the APP_ID that has been published, so I know that it isn't a whitelisting issue.

The code I use for discovery is completed by the CastCompanionLibrary. This is what I use once the `onCastDeviceDetected()` callback is called:

```
mCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {

            @Override
            public void onFailed(int resourceId, int statusCode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended() was called with cause: " + cause);
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectivityRecovered() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCastDeviceDetected(final MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
                if (!MyApplication.isFtuShown(Home.this)) {
                    MyApplication.setFtuShown(Home.this);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Route is visible: " + info);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mediaRouteMenuItem.isVisible()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Cast Icon is visible: " + info.getName());
                                //showFtu();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        };
```

MyApplication.class:

```
public static boolean isFtuShown(Context ctx) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    return sharedPref.getBoolean(FTU_SHOWN_KEY, false);
}

public static void setFtuShown(Context ctx) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    sharedPref.edit().putBoolean(FTU_SHOWN_KEY, true).commit();
}
```

Comment: What size is "large"? How many chromecast devices do they have on that network? Can they discover Google Play Music?

Comment: There is like 10 or more devices on that network. Other apps such as YouTube and Google Music are able to detect the chromecast devices. They also pick up on devices such as Xbox Ones and Smart TVs. What I mean by 'large' is that it's a wireless network for a dorm on campus.

Comment: The expected behavior should be very similar to Google Play Music in terms of discovery. In general, it is a bad idea to have a "dorm-wide" wifi network for chormecasts; you definitely don't want to mistakenly cast a video to your next-door chromecast, nor want to be interrupted if they do the same. In terms of numbers, having "too" many on the same network with the current discovery approach is a bit of an issue which we are trying to address in future releases. Please have them try the CastVideos-android sample app to see if that behaves similarly or not.

Comment: Oh okay; so it is a known issue with having too many devices using the CastCompanion library? I had him try the MediaRouter-Cast-Button android project here: https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android, but he was still unable to discover any devices. I will have him try the CastVideos-Android sample app to see if he has the same issues. Do you know specifically where the issue lies in the CastCompanionLibrary so I could look? Or does the CastCompanion library pretty much follow the same discovery logic of the link I posted?

Comment: CCL is a wrapper around the android Cast SDK so it doesn't do any discovery of its own, hence any app that uses the Cast SDK should behave the same way.

Comment: It could have something to do with the way their network is setup.  The TTL Chromecast uses is 1. You could do some packet sniffing to figure out exactly what/why it's not being detected.  See here http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/technotes/7-6/chromecastDG76/ChromecastDG76.html#pgfId-43238 for an interesting write up.